# Least squares with a quadratic inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, least-squares, qcqp

Is there a closed form solution for the following least squares problem:
$$ \min_\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{a+Bx}\|^2 ~~\text{s.t}~~\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 \leq \alpha^2$$
where $\mathbf{a} \in \mathbb{C^{M\times 1}}$ and $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{C^{M\times N}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends.

Consider the unconstrained least squares problem

$$ \min_\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{a+Bx}\|^2. $$

This problem has the solution $\mathbf{x}^\star = - (\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{a}  $. It is clear that $\mathbf{x}^\star $ is also the solution to your problem if $\|\mathbf{x}^\star\|^2 \leq \alpha^2$. In this case, you have an analytical solution.

However, if $\|\mathbf{x}^\star\|^2 > \alpha^2$, you have to consider the constrained problem

$$ \min_\mathbf{x}\|\mathbf{a+Bx}\|^2 + \lambda \|\mathbf{x}\|^2, $$ where $\lambda >0 $ is the Lagrange-Multiplier. This problem has the solution

$$\mathbf{x}^\star = - (\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{B} + \lambda \mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{a}$$

For the proper Lagrange-Multiplier $\lambda$, $\|\mathbf{x}^\star\|^2 = \alpha^2$ holds true. However, there is no analytical way to determine $\lambda$ which can be found by using bi-section search.

Comment: You are welcome! plz vote up :-)

Comment: I believe the unconstrained solution is $\mathbf{x}^\star = - (\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{a}  $. It's missing the inverse, correct?

Comment: correct, sorry for the mistake. I edit my post!

Comment: How do I find $\lambda$? What should be the starting value? how to iterate it?

Comment: @SagiShadur, Have a look at my solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2402360/33.