# Solution for $ \arg \min_{ {x}^{T} x = 1} { x}^{T} A x - {c}^{T} x $ - Quadratic Function with Non Linear Equality Constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

$$\min_{x^Tx=1} x^TAx-c^Tx$$

looks like a simple QPQC problem. If $A$ is positive semi-definite, can I get the solution by first getting $x=A^{-1}c$ and then projecting $x:=\dfrac{x}{\|x\|}$ to make sure $x^Tx=1$.

I hope to solve the problem using gradient descent method without solving any eigen-system problems. Any references related to this problem are also helpful.

Comment: No, you cannot. This will not give you the right answer in most cases.

Comment: But I'll bet its possible to prove that the Lagrangian approach gives the exact solution...

Comment: @MichaelGrant what do you mean by lagrangian approach? KKT?

Comment: Yep, that's right

Comment: if you want to solve that problem algorithmically, you need just find the root of $\| (A+\lambda I)^{-1} c \|^{-2} - 1 = 0$ for $\lambda > 0$ using secant or newton method.

Comment: @user251257 can you tell me how you derive the equation? $\lambda$ can be any positive number?

Comment: @E.J. Oh, I forgot the factor $1/2$. Thats follows from the KKT conditions $2Ax - c + \lambda 2 I x = 0$ and $x^T x = 1$. Also it is possible that $\lambda \le 0$, my bad. It is basically the same method as in solving the trust region subproblem. There are some edge and hard cases. It is little bit too broad for stackexchange.

Comment: is the matrix A at least psd? have you seen: http://users.clas.ufl.edu/hager/papers/Regular/sphere.pdf ?

Answer (score 2):

I'll do it without having to invert $A$, so no Newton's method. Also, KKT won't help you because the equality constraint is not convex.

When all else fails: do projected gradient descent.  Here's some pseudo code for minimizing $f(x) = \langle x, Ax + c \rangle$ s.t. $||x||=1$.

1. choose a initial unit vector $x$
2. $\nabla f(x) \leftarrow Ax + c.$
3. $x \leftarrow x - \tau \nabla f(x)$ for some $\tau>0$
4. $x \leftarrow x/||x||$
5. If converged, terminate, else return to step 2

Here's a plot of the iterates for a random $A$ and $c$ that I did quickly using backtracking to choose $\tau$ using initial point $\sqrt{2}(1,1).$
[image: Projected gradient descent for random $A$ and $c$ and initial point $\sqrt{2}(1,1)$]

The solver behaves very nicely for a random PSD matrix $A$,
[image: projected gradient descent]

Comment: Wait, so why won't KKT help you here? They're necessary conditions of optimality always, independent of convexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you relax your constraint to $ {x}^{T} x \leq 1 $ you can have easy solution.
I solved it for Least Squares, but it will be the same for you (Just adjust the matrices / vectors accordingly).

If you look into the solution you can infer how to deal with cases the solution has norm less than 1.

The solution below uses inversion of matrix.
But you could easily replace this step in any iterative solver of linear equation.

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\text{minimize} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & {x}^{T} x \leq 1
\end{alignat*}
$$

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \lambda \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \lambda \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right) $$

The KKT Conditions are given by:

$$
\begin{align*}
\nabla L \left( x, \lambda \right) = {A}^{T} \left( A x - b \right) + 2 \lambda x & = 0 && \text{(1) Stationary Point} \\
\lambda \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right) & = 0 && \text{(2) Slackness} \\
{x}^{T} x & \leq 1 && \text{(3) Primal Feasibility} \\
\lambda & \geq 0 && \text{(4) Dual Feasibility}
\end{align*}
$$

From (1) one could see that the optimal solution is given by:

$$ \hat{x} = {\left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda I \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b $$

Which is basically the solution for [Tikhonov Regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) of the Least Squares problem.

Now, from (2) if $ \lambda = 0 $ it means $ {x}^{T} x = 1 $ namely $ \left\| {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b \right\|_{2} = 1 $.

So one need to check the Least Squares solution first.
If $ \left\| {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b \right\|_{2} \leq 1 $ then $ \hat{x} = {\left( {A}^{T} A \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b $.

Otherwise, one need to find the optimal $ \hat{\lambda} $ such that $ \left\| {\left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda I \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b \right\| = 1 $.

For $ \lambda \geq 0 $ the function:

$$ f \left( \lambda \right) = \left\| {\left( {A}^{T} A + \lambda I \right)}^{-1} {A}^{T} b \right\| $$

Is monotonically descending and bounded below by $ 0 $.

[image]

Hence, all needed is to find the optimal value by any method by starting at $ 0 $.

Basically the methods is solving iteratively [Tikhonov Regularized Least Squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization) problem.

A demo code + solver can be found in my [StackExchange Mathematics Q2399321 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q2399321).

If you want I can even get you another solution using pure Gradient Descent.

Comment: Another approach is given by [On Convergence of Projected Gradient Descent for Minimizing a Large Scale Quadratic over the Unit Sphere](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8918830).