# How to rewrite the matrix optimization problem to a convex form?

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Consider the following optimization problem:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
p^*=&\min_{\Omega}
& &  \|\Omega Q + Q\Omega^T+2M\| \\
&\text{ s.t.} & & \Omega = -\Omega^T \\
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}

Note

1. $Q = qq^T$, where $\|q\|=1$ and $q\in\mathbb{R}^4$. So $Q\succeq0$.
2. $M\in\mathcal{S}^4$, i.e., it is symmetric.
3. $Q$, $M$ are given.
4. $\|\cdot\|$ can be spectral norm, or Frobenius norm.

So the matrix variable is $\Omega$, which is skew-symmetric.

This optimization problem is obvious not convex since $\Omega$ is not psd or pd. Is there any way to rewrite it as a convex optimization problem?

Thanks

Note:

This problem is from the Sylvester equation $$AX+XB=C,$$ with $X=\Omega$. However, here $2M\neq C$ and it does not meet the condition which guarantees the unique solution. So I want to find the best $\Omega$ such that $\|\cdot\|$ is minimized. Also there is a constraint on $\Omega$.

Comment: Why not? Objective is convex, constraint is affine.

Comment: @A.Γ. Should the variable $\Omega$ be positive semidefinite s.t. the optimization becomes convex?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Sure, just edit it.

Comment: Have you considered using a Lagrange multiplier (matrix)? Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510808/339790).

Comment: No. Skew-symmetric matrices build a linear subspace as they satisfy $\Omega+\Omega^T=0$. You may prove straightforward that if $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ are skew-symmetric then its linear combination is skew-symmetric as well.

Comment: Did you make progress?