# Solving a variant of an orthogonal Procrustes problem

Tags: matrices, optimization, svd, stiefel-manifolds, procrustes-problem

While reading the following paper on an optimization problem, there was a variant of an orthogonal Procrustes problem, where the solution is an element of the Stiefel manifold. The authors provided a closed-form solution, but I couldn't understand how they derived it!

- T. Neumann, K. Varanasi, C. Theobalt, M. Magnor, M. Wacker, [Compressed manifold modes for mesh processing](https://vcai.mpi-inf.mpg.de/files/CMM14.pdf), Eurographics Symposium on Geometry Processing 2014.

Given $Y$ is an $n \times k$ matrix and $D$ is an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix of strictly positive values on its main diagonal, the following optimization problem in $n \times k$ matrix $\Psi$

$$ {\bf \Psi}^{*} = \arg\min_{{\bf \Psi}, {\bf \Psi}^{\top}{\bf \Psi} = {\bf I}} \left\Vert {\bf D}^{-\frac12} {\bf \Psi} - {\bf Y} \right\Vert_2^2 $$

The $\left\Vert\cdot\right\Vert_2$ refers to the Frobenius norm, and the solution they used is as follows:

$$ {\bf \Psi}^{*} = \bf{Y}\bf{V}\bf{W}^{-\frac12}\bf{V}^{\top} $$

where $\bf{V}$, $\bf{W}$ and $\bf{V}^{\top}$ are obtained via the SVD decomposition

$$ (\bf{D}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bf{Y})^{\top}(\bf{D}^{\frac{1}{2}}\bf{Y}) = \bf{V}\bf{W}\bf{V}^{\top} $$

I attached the screenshot of the problem from the paper (we want to solve equation 10, the equations of interest are 14, 15 and 16), any help is appreciated!

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Please clarify in what sense this is a variant of the orthogonal Procrustes problem.

Comment: If the Frobenius norm were [used](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2510808/339790)

Comment: Looking at the paper, this norm is being used in ADMM in the penalty term.   It doesn't appear to matter whether you use the 2-norm or Frobenius norm for that purpose (they're topologically equivalent norms.)  It's quite common in my experience for machine learning folks to write 2-norm when they mean the Frobenius norm.

Comment: So, if it's Frobenius norm, how to solve this problem, I looked at the thread you sent @RodrigodeAzevedo but I can't see how they derived the solution in equation 16

Comment: The transformation of (10) into (14) requires this to be the Frobenius norm.

Comment: Note that $\min \| D^{-1/2} \Psi - Y \|_{F}^{2} $ is equivalent to minimizing the Frobenius norm squared of the transpose, $\min \| \Psi^{T} D^{-T/2} -Y^{T} \|_{F}^{2}$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers
Do we know how to solve $\left\Vert \bf{\Psi}^{\top}(\bf{D}^{\frac{-1}{2}})^{\top} - \bf{Y}^{\top} \right\Vert_F^2$ under the condition of being in the Stiefel manifold in closed form?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and I'm not convinced the paper is correct in the solution it gives, but a quick google scholar search reveals some papers on this variation on the procrustes problem.